¿Como llevar a produccion una aplicacion con Next.js cuando tiene rutas dinamicas?
Cuando genero el build utilizando output: 'export, se me genera una carpeta llamada out, son archivos estaticos por lo cual no funcionan mis paginas y no muestran ningun dato que obtengo de una url externa. como puedo solucionar esto.
Gracias

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
